# How to modify an object property in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, object

I have an object that takes the following form:

```js
booking Object {
  "2019-11-29": Object {
    "selected": true,
  },
  "2019-11-30": Object {
    "selected": true,
  },
}
```

that I want to modify through invoking a function. More specifically, I want to toggle the `selected` property, which is Boolean.

I want to invoke a function that 1) checks to see if a certain key exists in the object, "2019-11-29" in this example, and if it does, 2) toggle the `selected` property, while everything else in the object remain the same.

My following code toggles the `selected` property temporarily, but doesn't save it in the state.

```js
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState([])    
    const [booking, setBooking] = useState({})    

    const select = day => {
        let markedDay = day.dateString

        // first checks in the "selected" array to see if the "markedDay" exists
        if(selected.includes(markedDay)){
            // toggles the property within the "booking" object
            booking[markedDay] = {
                selected: !booking[markedDay].selected
            }

            setBooking(booking) // this hook doesn't update the state with the newly toggled object property
        }

        // saves the "markedDay" into a new array if it doesn't exist in the array already
        const newSelected = [...selected, markedDay];

        // assigns the property "selected" to the newly entered date and combines it with the pre-existing object
        let obj = newSelected.reduce((c, v) => Object.assign(c, {
          [v]: {
            selected: true,
          }
        }), {})
        setSelected(newSelected)
        setBooking(obj);
    }
```

What I mean by temporarily is that when I console log the `booking` object right after the `booking[markedDay].selected` has been toggled, it will show that the property shows as `false`, which is the intended result.  However, if I were to console log `booking` outside of the `if` statement, the global state still shows the property as `true`.

P.S. I have mistakenly named the array state `selected` of the `useState` the same as the property of the object `selected`, but they are unrelated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update nested state properties in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040721/how-to-update-nested-state-properties-in-react)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're directly modifying the state, that's why the updates aren't reflected in the component. To achieve what you want you can use functional form of `setState` and object spread:

```
 if (selected.includes(markedDay)) {
   setBooking(currentBooking => {
     return {
       ...currentBooking,
       [markedDay]: {
         ...currentBooking[markedDay],
         selected: !currentBooking[markedDay].selected
       }
     }
   })
 }
```

Comment: for some reason the property is still not being toggled. Should I be making use of `currentBooking` in the return?

Comment: Ah, my bad, of course it has to be `currentBooking` instead of `booking`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but it's still not toggling the boolean property. Console.logging `markedDay` and `currentBooking` show correct states, but console.logging `booking` still show the `selected` property as true

Comment: @Kevvv where are you logging those?

Comment: inside the `if` statement for `currentBooking` and `markedDay` and outside for `booking` where the state is ultimately being used.

Comment: Hmm, isn't `selected` an array of objects? In that case `selected.includes(markedDay)` might not work. Try removing the condition and see if the value gets toggled.

Comment: `selected` is just an array like `["2019-11-22", "2019-11-23"]`. The `if` condition is true for `selected.includes(markedDay)` when `markedDay` is passed more than once so the logic inside the `if` statement is being executed.

Comment: Then the code should work. Try checking the state values inside the render or do `useEffect(() => { console.log(booking)}, [booking])` to make sure you get the proper state value.

Comment: had to put the rest of the code in the `else` statement. The rest portion of the code was overriding what was being done inside the `if` statement. Thank you for your help!